# How to import a file edited in Notepad++ to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, notepad++

I exported a MySQL table as CSV (Just CSV and not "CSV for MS Excel") and edited in excel. Then I opened it with Notepad++ in order to change character encoding to UTF-8. Now I want to import this Notepad++ file back to the MySQL table.

I don't know what next. I tried copying it to excel and save as CSV and import the CSV file, but it doesn't work.

I use shared hosting. I exported the table from phpMyAdmin.
Export->Format->CSV

Please help me.

```
925,1,2020-04-29  20:00:00,2020-04-29  20:00:00,,ck-X{´¯nsâ ]nXmhv,,publish,closed,closed,,ck-x{´¯nsâ-]nxmhv,,,2020-04-29  20:00:00,2020-04-29  20:00:00,,0,https://example.com/questions/ck-x{´¯nsâ-]nxmhv,0,lp_question,,0
926,1,2020-04-29  20:00:00,2020-04-29  20:00:00,,B[p-\nI ck-X{´¯nsâ ]nXmhv,,publish,closed,closed,,b[p-\ni-ck-x{´¯nsâ-]nxmhv,,,2020-04-29  20:00:00,2020-04-29  20:00:00,,0,https://example.com/questions/b[p-\ni-ck-x{´¯nsâ-]nxmhv,0,lp_question,,0
```

Comment: the easiest way is to use mysql workbench or phpworkbench, or what ever you use to mange your database

Comment: why did you export your table in excel. if you wanted to export your datbase. you can choose .sql format. Then you can edit your table in notepad or any other text editor. Although @nbk is right you should use mysql workbench which is free.

Comment: post your table code and how did you export your from mysql to excel (procedure) here

Comment: @Aman I exported the table in excel because I had to edit the file with some formulae.